# Prove that $(\frac{n+1}{4})^{n+1} < n!$ by induction

Tags: induction, factorial

Prove that $(\frac{n+1}{4})^{n+1} < n!$ for integer $n\geq 1$ by induction

Comment: @Jazzachi I tried to use n!>((n+1)/e)^n

Comment: @Jazzachi Soon I got (4/e)^(n+1) ?>? (n+2)/4, where I stucked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base case is trivial.

By induction hypotheses we have $({{n+1}\over4})^{n+1} < n!$

Note that $(1+{1\over n})^n < e$ for all $n$ by definition of $e$.

So $({{n+2}\over4})^{n+2} = ({{n+2}\over4})({{n+2}\over{n+1}})^{n+1}({{n+1}\over4})^{n+1} < ({{n+2}\over4})\cdot e\cdot n! < (n+1)!$

Comment: You can't use $e$.

Comment: Why can't we use $e$? Is it stated in the question?